# how to set the path in this file

Tags: java, sphinx

im using Sphinx and i have configured my gammar model path which is build\class\FYP

but in my configuration file i just wanted to put FYP in the configuration component

as follow

```
 <component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar">
    <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
    <property name="grammarLocation"
         value="resource:/FYP/"/>
    <property name="grammarName" value="word"/>
<property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
</component>
```

but when i want to deploy the application the said folder cleans and the deployed jar file is not working because of it misses this grammar model.

this is the path 
C:\Users\Pradeep\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FYPApplication11

which has the grammar model at the moment.

but when i put like this

```
 <component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar">
    <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
    <property name="grammarLocation"
         value="resource:/C:\Users\Pradeep\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FYPApplication11/"/>
    <property name="grammarName" value="word"/>
<property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
</component>
```

or using

\ lines also didnt work

can someone help me to make this project to deploy as a jar file. because of this path issue the application is not working when i deploy in Netbeans

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation, the "grammerLocation" property can take two types of values:

- A resource locator (for resources in jars, classpath)
- A URL

So on windows, in your case you can do:

```
<component name="jsgfGrammar" type="edu.cmu.sphinx.jsapi.JSGFGrammar">
    <property name="dictionary" value="dictionary"/>
    <property name="grammarLocation" value="file:/C:/Users/Pradeep/Documents/NetBeansProjects/FYPApplication11/"/>
    <property name="grammarName" value="word"/>
    <property name="logMath" value="logMath"/>
</component>
```

Comment: wow it works. i love stackoverflow. thanks a lot naikus. appreciate it a lot. u are soo great